# Variable inside bash's while loop never changed

Tags: bash

Why does the following code always outputs "0"?

```
#!/bin/bash

RETVAL=0
echo -e '1\n2' | while read number; do
    RETVAL=1
done

echo $RETVAL
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124167/bash-variable-scope

Comment: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Piped_%60while-read'_loop_starts_subshell

Answer (score 3):

The while loop is part of a pipeline, and therefore runs in a subshell. Variables set in the subshell (`RETVAL=1`) don't affect the parent shell (`echo $RETVAL`).

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how the echo is not passing an EOF / Ctrl D to the while read.

If you pull the echo out and enter a Ctrl D to the while loop it will work as expected.

Not sure how to send a Ctrl D via an echo.